# Json with different website structure

Tags: json, web-crawler

I'm writing  a content gathering program that will simply read data on specified web pages, and save it for later analysis. I don't need it to search for links or related data, just gather all data from websites. It doesn't matter that the content will change daily. The problem is if the structure of the website is changing. Are there any possibilities or products that monitor structure changes on specified websites and present them somehow?

How can I easily parse JSONs/XML-s with the same content type but different structure?

Answer (score 0):

For parsing you can use Json.NET and JObject for different structure